# Can I use OpenAM for REST API Security between two servers?

Tags: security, rest, openam

(If this question is not adequate, I'll close it later...)

We are using OpenAM for SSO between our Applications.
 Some applications are on the container which is not supported by OpenAM agents, so we unified them into one Apache web server.
 OK, there's no problem about SSO itself.

Now, I took a new work.
 In some use-cases or business scenarios, Server A calls Server B's REST APIs. (triggered by client or not)
 At this point in time, that call is not secure.
 My duty is to make it secure...
 I thought OpenAM can play OAuth2/STS Provider, so I Considered using OpenAM for solving this subject.
 But (as I mentioned above) in some cases, just server-to-server calls are arisen without intervention of Client/User.
 Hmm... I am confused.
 I don't know or define OpenAM's role in that situation.

Can I use OpenAM in this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a good use-case for OAuth2 client credentials grant: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.4

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  
 Now I'm reading OpenAM Manual again...  
 Though still I don't understand thoroughly about that, I hope I can find solutions.